# How to call a commit and dispatch asynchronously from same action?

Tags: vuejs2, vuex, vuex-modules

I want to perform an action after mutation has done it's job.

The mutation (`SOME_MUTATION`) is from same store and the action(`test/testAction`) is from a module

```
someAction(context, data) {
    context.commit('SOME_MUTATION', data) // this should be committed first
    context.dispatch('test/testAction') // this action should be dispatched after the above commit
}
```

Note: I don't know whether or not it is the default behaviour

Answer (score 0):

you would change your `someAction(context, data)` to this

```
someAction({commit, dispatch}, data) {
    call.action()
    .then(=> {
    commit('some_mutations',data)
    dispatch('another_action')
    }
}
```

using `{commit, dispatch}` will allow you use both inside action without having to say `context`. because actions only accept 2 parameters you pass both in as single object, so that you can still pass in the `data` parameter.

Comment: I would like to dispatch the action `another_action` only after the `some_mutations` mutation is committed

Comment: @Naresh, could you post more detail on what it is that your are trying to accomplish in your question? Such as the component you are calling the action from and if possible why does the mutation need to complete prior to dispatching action?

Comment: once the mutation is committed, I would like to assign the newly committed value in another module's state and I'm calling the action from `Home` component